# How do I push my work to my repository on Github from a terminal on Linux?

Tags: linux, git, github, git-push

I'm trying to upload my work on my local drive to a Github repository that I forked over. Here is the code I entered into the terminal:

```
cd Desktop
cd <project>
ls
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git log
git remote add publicrepot <github link>
git remote publicrepo
git push -u publicrepo
git push --set-upstream publicrepo master
```

And then it gives me this message:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

How do I upload my work into the repository that I forked over from another account?

Comment: You should use git pull to get new change the repository, after git push again.

Comment: I'm curious: the error message tells you exactly what the problem is and what you should do (mirrored in the fact that both the comment above me and the one answer so far tell exactly the same). Did you try that? Did it work?

Answer (score 2):

Before pushing changes to a remote, you must have all the changes the remote has (unless you are force-pushing, which you probably shouldn't do).  Try running

```
git pull
```

before your push.

Or, if you don't want a merge commit,

```
git pull --rebase
```